# "Interested on" or "interested in"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Which is correct: *interested on* or *interested in*?

Answer (score 23):

You can check questions like this using the [Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=8352434). “Interested in” gets 23703 results and “interested on” gets only 13.

Answer (score 12):

*Interested in chess* is correct. Nobody says *interested on chess*, for example.

Answer (score 8):

"In", only. One can also be "interested to [verb]", e.g. "I'd be interested to see whether he shows up.".